# non-const reference of type from an rvalue

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference

Consider the following code:

```
class Widget{};

template<typename T>
T &&foo2(T &&t){
    return std::forward<T>( t );
}

/// Return 1st element
template<typename T>
typename std::tuple_element<0, typename std::decay<T>::type >::type  &&foo(T &&t){
    return std::forward< typename std::tuple_element<0, typename std::decay<T>::type >::type >
            ( std::get<0>(t) );
}

Widget w;
auto list = std::make_tuple(
    w,
    Widget()
);


int main()
{
  auto &l  = foo(list );                      // This is NOT work
  //auto &l2 = foo2( std::get<0>(list) );     // This one works.
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d3b74ca6f043e45

When I tried to compile this I got the following error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Widget&' from an rvalue of type 'std::tuple_element<0ul, std::tuple<Widget, Widget> >::type {aka Widget}'
```

Well, and that would be ok, but:

- at first, that *Widget w* is not temporary. Why it treat it like temporary?
- at second, why foo2 works than?

P.S. As you see, I try to write function which operates both with lvalue and rvalue. If first element is temporary I want to return rvalue, if it is not - lvalue.

Comment: Are you aware that the type of `std::make_tuple(w, Widget())` is `std::tuple<Widget, Widget>` and not `std::tuple<Widget&, Widget&&>`? If you want to deduce a tuple of reference types you need [`std::forward_as_tuple(w, Widget())`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) which will return `std::tuple<Widget&, Widget&&>`. Or is the real problem here that you want a function that creates a tuple with an lvalue references for lvalue reference inputs, and a plain value for rvalue reference inputs?

Comment: I need a function that accepts both forward_as_tuple and make_tuple. And returns rvalue reference in first case, an lvalue reference in second (return value is one of tuple elements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tuple_element` returns the element type, not a reference type (unless the element type is itself a reference type).

You need to have it return a reference type if the type `T` is a reference type.

This can be expressed with a conditional:

```
typename std::conditional<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
    typename std::add_lvalue_reference<
        typename std::tuple_element<0, typename std::decay<T>::type >::type>::type,
    typename std::tuple_element<0, typename std::decay<T>::type >::type>::type
```

Or, more easily, using `decltype`, since `std::get` already performs this calculation for you:

```
decltype(std::get<0>(std::declval<T &&>())) &&
```

Comment: Should I, still, add `std::forward` to return value, while using `decltype(std::get<0>(std::declval<T &&>())) &&` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this much simpler:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T &&t) -> decltype(std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(t))) {
    return std::get<0>(t);
}
```

Comment: This will return a reference, or value?

Comment: @tower120 a reference.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(t))`?

Comment: Yes, and shouldn't we forward `std::get<0>` value, too?

Comment: @tower120 Not necessary, `decltype` will deduce an lvalue/rvalue reference type as appropriate for an lvalue/rvalue expression.

Comment: Just to clarify. If I need return member value from tuple, like: `return std::get<0>(t).value;`. Than I have to `add_lvalue_reference` like in ecatmur answer?

Comment: @tower120 @Casey already commented on this, `decltype` will do the job. check for your self `std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(foo(std::make_tuple(w, Widget())))>::value << std::endl;` == `true`

Comment: @40two I checked - it not work without `add_lvalue_reference` . That's why I asking. Look at `foo4` function here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d71333d9dda92f06

Comment: @40two Ok, but I talk about case when function have to return reference to id, not to Widget.

Comment: @tower120 that's another case.

Comment: Why is `std::forward` in the return type, but not in the return statement?

Answer (score 0):

`foo` returns an rvalue reference so you can't bind it to an `auto&` because that requires an lvalue reference.

`foo2` uses a "universal reference" that evaluates to an lvalue reference in this case because std::get returns an lvalue reference and you perfectly forward it to the return value.

Comment: Can I change `foo` so it return "universal reference" too ?

Comment: Universal reference is not an actual thing, it just means that we the parameter can have either an lvalue reference and rvalue reference type depending on template instantiation (which depends on the supplied argument at the call site). 

What you want is in 40two's answer, but make sure to forward the parameter `t`.