# C++11 templated function with rvalue param call

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference

In some class O, I have templated function `test2`:

```
struct A{int value;};

struct O{
    A value;

    template<typename Args>
    static void test2(Args &&args){
        std::cout << std::endl << "!!!" << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(args)>::value << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Than, I want to call this function from another one:

```
template<typename Args>
void test(Args &&args){
    using t = decltype(std::forward<Args>(args).value);
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(args)>::value;
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(std::forward<Args>(args).value)>::value;
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<t>::value;

    // All ok
    O.test2(std::forward<Args>(args).value);            

    // Alvays rvalue, even if agrs is lvalue
    O::template test2<t>(
        std::forward<t>(
            std::forward<Args>(args).value
        )
    );

   // Nor work at all, cant cast A to A&&
   O::template test2<t>(
        std::forward<Args>(args).value
    );
);

}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bbf040904845a54

If I just pass `std::forward<Args>(args).value` without specifying template type, it deduce type correctly, but what if I have to pass type, how should I call function than?

It seems I can't manually deduce type correctly.

---

**UPDATE**

I need to specify arguments explicitly, because I have function like this (pseudo-code):

```
//initially call wind from somewhere.

// Tuple defined in class and is std::tuple
template<class Callback, class ...Args>
void wind(Tuple&& tuple, Callback &&callback){   
    using elementT = decltype(std::get<index>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)));

    ///
    /// !!! Problem here !!!
    ///
    callback.template operator()<elementT, Args...>(  std::get<index>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))  );              // std::get automatically return &/&&

   // recursivly call wind until the end
   wind<Callback, Args...>( std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<Callback>(callback));
}

// callback looks like:
struct CallMe{   
  // Args provide type info. No function arguments here.
  template<class Data, class ...Args>
  void operator(Data &&data){

  }
}
```

This question related to call both - wind and callback() functions.

Comment: Do you mean `callback` when you say `data` within `wind`? If so, I think you have some undefined behavior there because `callback` might be moved into the `operator()` argument before you invoke `operator()` on `callback`.

Comment: No, I updated question with real application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on knowledge that objects, inside rvalue referenced object, also rvalue referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380677/are-objects-inside-rvalue-referenced-object-also-rvalue-referenced).
I decide to ended up with this (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083200/1559666):

```
template<class T, class FieldT>
using addRefU = typename std::conditional<
                            std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value,
                            typename std::add_rvalue_reference< FieldT >::type,
                            typename std::conditional<
                                std::is_rvalue_reference<FieldT>::value,
                                typename std::add_rvalue_reference< FieldT >::type,
                                typename std::add_lvalue_reference< FieldT >::type
                            >::type
                        >::type;
```

---

```
    T           T::value(FieldT)    resolve
------------------------------------------------------------
 rvalue         lvalue              rvalue
 rvalue         rvalue              rvalue
 lvalue         rvalue              rvalue
 lvalue         lvalue              lvalue
```

---

```
using t = addRefU<decltype(args), decltype(args.value)>;
O::template test2<t>(
    static_cast<t>(args.value)
);
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40d10f5a2f45c288

Short enough, as for me.

*P.S. If someone have some precautions about this, I would gladly listen to them.*

Answer (score 5):

```
template<typename Args>
static void test2(Args&& args)
{ ... }
```

In the above function, even though the parameter type looks like an rvalue reference, it can bind to both rvalue and lvalue arguments. This is colloquially known as a ***universal reference***. If the function argument is an rvalue of type `U`, then `T` is deduced as `U`, and `T&&` is `U&&`, an rvalue reference, which is straightforward. However, when the function argument is an lvalue of type `U`, then `T` will be deduced as `U&`, which means the function parameter type would be `U& &&`, which undergoes ***reference collapsing*** to become `U&`. However, for these special rules to apply, the type ***must be deduced***.

---

```
O::test2(std::forward<Args>(args).value); // changed O.test2 to O::test2
```

In this case, the template parameter type is being deduced from the function argument. The argument itself is an lvalue, so the type of the function parameter `args` is also an lvalue.

---

```
O::template test2<t>(
    std::forward<t>(
        std::forward<Args>(args).value
    )
);
```

The difference here is that you've explicitly specified the template parameter type for `test2`. No deduction is taking place, and the function parameter is a simple rvalue reference in this case. It can only bind to rvalues, and you provide it this rvalue due to the outer `std::forward<t>` cast (here `t = A`). It has the same effect as `static_cast<A&&>(value)`.

---

```
O::template test2<t>(
    std::forward<Args>(args).value
);
```

The last case should've explained why this doesn't work. As explained above, `test2` can only bind to an rvalue in this case, and without the second `std::forward` from above, you're trying to bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference parameter, which fails.

Comment: Well, can I make compiler work about deducing type manually? I really need to pass that template parameter, because I have variadic template list going after it, on my live application.

Comment: @tower120 You can `std::move(std::forward<Args>(args).value)` in the last case to make it work. But I don't see why this is necessary even if you have a parameter pack following this argument. Maybe if you updated the question with what you're trying to do, someone could suggest another way?

Comment: Which type it use as template parameter here `O::test2(std::forward<Args>(args).value);` ?

Comment: "But I don't see why this is necessary even if you ..." - what do you mean? You don't understand why function &&, or why I have to specify template argument explicitly?

Comment: @tower120 It'll be deduced as an lvalue reference in that case. And I don't understand why it's necessary to specify the template argument.

Comment: Can I manually cast it to lvalue than? I updated my question.

Comment: I can't think of a way to make it work with what you have. Can't you instead wrap everything in some `struct`s like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4e41d527c6740d4) so you don't have to mention `Args` everywhere?

Comment: Well yes, but than I have to recreate my callback each time I want to add arg to it. You see, I have some callback class. And I have some tuple and tuple indide tuple (table, or 2D array), and I want to iterate it with that callback. I make an instance of Callback (because callback will store some calculated data), and pass it to this iterator. Before call callback I want to pass an info to it - from which tuple it called. Using your way, I'll have to recreate Callback instance each time before call. I think about `static_cast` solution, after all,  `std::get` works similar to that.

Comment: @tower120 The updated part of your question is worthy of being a separate question (you need to clean up the code a bit and make it compile first). I'd be curious to see if someone has an elegant solution to your problem.