# Are objects inside rvalue referenced object, also rvalue referenced?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Are objects inside rvalue referenced object, also rvalue referenced?

```
struct A{
};

struct B{
   A a2;
};

//template<class B>
void test(B &&b){

    // 1. Is this the correct way?
    auto &&in3 = std::forward<B>(b).a2;
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(in3)>::value;
    // return true

    // 2. or this?
    auto &&in4 = b.a2;
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<decltype(in4)>::value;    
    // return false        
}

test(B());
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcf0f7dc4cc0440e

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, members of rvalues are themselves rvalues. This was clarified by [DR 421](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#421)

But that is irrelevant here:

> auto &&in4 = b.a2;

`b` is not an rvalue, it's an lvalue (simple rule of thumb: it has a name).

To restore the value category it had when passed to the function you need to `forward` it

Comment: The issue seems to be clarified further [here](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616).